# Convert length 1 nested lists into strings

Tags: python, list

I have this list, in Python, with some nested lists inside with length 1:

[**['7746']**, '12', '1929', '8827', **['7']**, '8837', '128']

I want to get rid of the lists and just keep the string inside and get:

[**'7746'**, '12', '1929', '8827', **'7'**, '8837', '128']

How do I do this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python. Sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: Well I've been trying the whole day with for loops, range function and stuff like that. My knowledge of Python is quite limited, as you can tell. So not many things I can try... I just thought there would be a quick way to convert a length 1 list into a normal string...

Comment: nested = [['7746'], ['12', '1929', '8827'], ['7'], ['8837', '128']]

empty = list()


for stuff in range(len(nested)):
 
 if len(nested[stuff]) > 1:
  x = nested[stuff]
  for stuff in x:
   empty.append(stuff)
 else:
  empty.append(stuff)
print empty

Comment: That's some code I tried. But the problem is, for length 1 list, I'm getting the range, not the value inside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and a ternary conditional:

```
empty = [(x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x) for x in nested]
```

Alternatively, the obvious solution with a simple loop:

```
empty = []
for x in nested:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        empty.append(x[0])
    else:
        empty.append(x)
```